# Distance calibration between GNSS RTK receiver and display/processing device?

Tags: gps, land-survey, dgps

Are there any known procedures for calibrating a precise position of an external processing/display device (e.g. a smartphone or a tablet) *relative to the GNSS receiver*?

Apparently, such a procedure is unnecessary when the display/processing unit is mounted on the pole in a fixed position like this:

[image: fixed mounted processing unit]

However, if the distance between the receiver and the processing unit is not fixed, how does one handle measurement and calibration of this distance? Imagine, for example, a surveying session when one has to walk around the area holding only the display/processing unit in their hands, while the receiver position does not change (think underground utility mapping).

Or, when a GNSS receiver is mounted in a backpack like this:

[image: example]

When we talk about centimetre accuracy, any hands and/or backpack movements will introduce a measurement error. Of course, most of the tablets/smartphones have IMUs whose readings should help make necessary adjustments, but the question of initial distance calibration remains open.